Results of Shadow catcher are different from Viewport
I'm creating some renders that I need to export as PNGs with corresponding floor shadows.
It looks correct in the viewport, but when I render, the shadows come out very harsh and dark. I've searched everywhere for solutions but can't find anything to help me.
I assume there must be a solution, but I'm unable to find it. I'm attaching the .blend file as a sample because I can't share the original models, but the issue persists. I'm using Cycles Blender 4.0


Blender File

Hello and welcome to BSE. I don't see anything wrong. Take note that your background is darker in the second image. I experimented and the shadows will look darker with darker background.
